# Which language except js-like can be used to create react apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There was a front-end language with react support, if I correctly remember, it was a strict-typed language. But I don't remember its name. Who can suggest?
It'c certainly not Elm
P.S. not TypeScript

Comment: Are you thinking of Flow? I don't know  whether it can be used for React however.

Comment: Theoretically any language that compiles to JavaScript can be used for React, but it's not certain you will get the syntactical sugar of jsx. Maybe PureScript? CoffeeScript?

Comment: @Pointy yes, could be! Flow can be setup to work with react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I found the answer, it's ReScript https://rescript-lang.org/